# Collision2D not works properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, collision, game-development

Currently I am working on 2D Platformer game and there is a bug that gives me headache. Basicly, if our player, collide to an enemy object he dies. on the other hand if he collect a coin, that means he finished the level. According to this situations, the code actives winPanel, or losePanel. But I dont know why, code only works on lose situations, does not active winPanel.

This part is where I check and identify collisions according to the tags.

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
       
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            GetComponent<TimeControl>().enabled = false;
            Die();
        }

         else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Finish"))
        {
            
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            StartCoroutine(Wait(true));
            
        }
    }
```

Then I am sending true or false to the "Wait" function for enabling win or lose panel.

```
 IEnumerator Wait(bool win)
    {
       
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2f);
        Time.timeScale = 0;

        if (win==true)
        {
            
            winPanel.SetActive(true);
        }

        else
        {
            losePanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

The game is perfectly working on lose or die situations, but not working when player collect coin tagged "Finish".

Comment: does your finish object has a tag called "Finish" ? Add a debug log at the beginning of the collision enter method and print each objects tag that player collides with and you can see what happens when it collides with finish.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK Of course my object has a tag "Finish". I checked numerous times. Also, I tried the same thing you said. In console window, I couldn't see the coin object's name. Somehow player does not collide with the coin object.

Comment: does your finish object's collider trigger field is tick ? if so it means that you need to check it under OnTriggerEnter2D method

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Your coin does not have a "Finish" tag.
2. Your coin's collider 2D is treigger that means player can run in to it. But in that situation u need to use another method to detect: OnTriggerEnter2D.
   Here is unity documentation page: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html